# Why are the thumbnail images not loading?

Tags: 8, media

I am using Drupal 8, and have just moved my site to shared hosting. When I upload a standard image field on my shared hosting environment, the thumbnail image does not show up. This works perfectly on my local (WAMP) development environment.

The full sized image is in sites/default/files/2017-02/redstart.jpg and is displayed correctly.

The thumbnail address is /sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/2017-02/redstart.jpg and does not display (I assume it cannot create it).

I have checked all file permissions on the server, but cannot see anything wrong (directories are 0755, files 0644)
Any ideas anyone? Is there another setting somewhere that I need to update?

Comment: Do you have the correct folder owner?

Comment: Just to be sure this is not a permission issue, set 775 for sites/default/files and it subdirectories and give it another try. This will cover No Sssweat's question aswell.

Comment: OK thanks. I am logged in as admin, so should be OK with 755. I tried changing to 775, and it worked for the next one I added.  However, when I deleted the "redstart" and tried to re-add it, same issue, the thumbnail is missing. So I tried some more. So far 2 successful thumbnails, three failures. I am confused.

Comment: "Logged in as admin" - you mean logged in in Drupal? That doesn't make a difference. File system permissions do not care about Drupal users and roles. Make sure that your system allows the web server user (often `www-data`, `http` or `apache`) to write in the public files directory. Do this recursively, for all files and folders under the public files directory.

Comment: OK, not sure I have any control here. The apache/php web site is with a shared provider via cpanel. I only have one log in id to cpanel, and can only see one set of permissions on the directories. Should I check this with the provider?

Comment: did you upload the .htaccess files and set up mod rewrite or whatever else is necessary to properly redirect non-existing files to Drupal? Do your urls contain index.php?

Comment: not tried that yet, after further experimentation it looks like any .JPG file works, i.e. I can see the thumbnail, but .jpg (lower case) does not work. Is this possible? Tghe same image file works if I change it from .jpg to .JPG. Also the .JPG is marked as text/x-generic rather than image/x-generic. What does that mean?

Comment: To test this further I created a new content type with just one image field, using all the defaults. If I add an image of type "jpg", the thumbnail does not get copied to the "styles" sub directory and the thumbnail does not show. If I add an image of type "JPG" all works fine.  Is this a bug in Drupal, or my hosting environment?